# Why am I getting a `null` when trying to display the details of a particular student?

Tags: java, object, linked-list

After adding a student object to the Linked List, I have tried displaying the details of that student but always end up with `null` at the output.

The `addStudent()` method in the **StudentRecords (GUI)** class is meant to call the method: `addStudent(Student aNewStudentObj)` in the **Manager** class which then creates a new object of a student with the details inputted by the user and stores that object into the Linked List. The `displayStudent(int studentId)` method in the Manager class should then be able to display the student and its details with the given `studentId` but in my case, I only get a `null` as mentioned already.

I have literally tried everything that I could think of and now I am starting to lose my hair because of the stress so I would very much appreciate all the help that I can get. Please.

All code below:

**StudentRecords (GUI)** class below:

```
package studentrecords;

/**
 *
 * @author azim1
 */
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StudentRecords implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField firstNameTextField;
    private JTextField surnameTextField;
    private JTextField yearOfStudyTextField;
    private JTextField emailTextField;
    private JTextField studentIdTextField;
    private JTextField moduleCodeTextField;
    private JTextField moduleMarkTextField;
    private JButton addStudentButton;
    private JButton addModuleButton;
    private JButton displayStudentButton;
    private JButton displayAllButton;
    private JButton displayMarksButton;
    private JButton deleteStudentButton;
    private JFrame frame;

    private Manager studentList = new Manager();

    private Student student;

    public StudentRecords() {

        frame = new JFrame("Student Records");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 3));

        JLabel firstNameLabel = new JLabel("First Name:");
        contentPane.add(firstNameLabel);

        JLabel surnameLabel = new JLabel("Surname:");
        contentPane.add(surnameLabel);

        JLabel nothing = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing);

        firstNameTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(firstNameTextField);

        surnameTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(surnameTextField);

        addStudentButton = new JButton("Add Student");
        contentPane.add(addStudentButton);
        addStudentButton.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel yearOfStudyLabel = new JLabel("Year of Study:");
        contentPane.add(yearOfStudyLabel);

        JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email:");
        contentPane.add(emailLabel);

        JLabel nothing1 = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing1);

        yearOfStudyTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(yearOfStudyTextField);

        emailTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(emailTextField);

        JLabel nothing2 = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing2);

        JLabel studentIdLabel = new JLabel("Student ID:");
        contentPane.add(studentIdLabel);

        JLabel nothing3 = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing3);

        JLabel nothing4 = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing4);

        studentIdTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(studentIdTextField);

        displayStudentButton = new JButton("Display Student");
        contentPane.add(displayStudentButton);
        displayStudentButton.addActionListener(this);

        displayMarksButton = new JButton("Display Marks");
        contentPane.add(displayMarksButton);
        displayMarksButton.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel moduleCodeLabel = new JLabel("Module Code:");
        contentPane.add(moduleCodeLabel);

        JLabel moduleMarkLabel = new JLabel("Module Mark:");
        contentPane.add(moduleMarkLabel);

        JLabel nothing5 = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing5);

        moduleCodeTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(moduleCodeTextField);

        moduleMarkTextField = new JTextField(15);
        contentPane.add(moduleMarkTextField);

        addModuleButton = new JButton("Add Module");
        contentPane.add(addModuleButton);
        addModuleButton.addActionListener(this);

        displayAllButton = new JButton("Display All");
        contentPane.add(displayAllButton);
        displayAllButton.addActionListener(this);

        JLabel nothing6 = new JLabel(" ");
        contentPane.add(nothing6);

        deleteStudentButton = new JButton("Delete Student");
        contentPane.add(deleteStudentButton);
        deleteStudentButton.addActionListener(this);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StudentRecords sRecord = new StudentRecords();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals("Add Student")) {
            addStudent();
        }
        if (command.equals("Add Module")) {
            addModule();
        }
        if (command.equals("Display All")) {
            displayAll();
        }
        if (command.equals("Display Student")) {
            displayStudent();
        }
        if (command.equals("Display Marks")) {
            displayMarks();
        }
        if (command.equals("Delete Student")) {
            deleteStudent();
        }
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        String firstName
                = firstNameTextField.getText();
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        String surname
                = surnameTextField.getText();
        return surname;
    }

    public int getYearOfStudy() {
        int yearOfStudy
                = Integer.parseInt(yearOfStudyTextField.getText());
        return yearOfStudy;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        String email
                = emailTextField.getText();
        return email;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        int studentId
                = Integer.parseInt(studentIdTextField.getText());
        return studentId;
    }

    public String getModuleCode() {
        String moduleCode
                = moduleCodeTextField.getText();
        return moduleCode;
    }

    public int getModuleMark() {
        int moduleMark
                = Integer.parseInt(moduleMarkTextField.getText());
        return moduleMark;
    }

    public void addStudent() {

        studentList.addStudent(student);
    }

    public void addModule() {
        //search for the student withh the ID
        Student module = new Student(getFirstName(), getSurname(), getEmail(), getYearOfStudy(), getStudentId());
        module.addModule(getStudentId(), getModuleCode(), getModuleMark());
    }

    public void displayAll() {

        studentList.displayAll();
    }

    public void displayStudent() {

        studentList.displayStudent(getStudentId());
    }

    public void displayMarks() {

        studentList.displayMarks(getStudentId());
    }

    public void deleteStudent() {

        studentList.deleteStudent(getStudentId());
    }

}
```

**Student** class below:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 *
 * @author azim1
 */
public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private int yearOfStudy;
    private int studentId;
    private Queue<Module> mods = new LinkedList<>();

    public Student(String firstName, String surname, String email, int yearOfStudy, int studentId) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.surname = surname;;
        this.email = email;
        this.yearOfStudy = yearOfStudy;;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getYearOfStudy() {
        return yearOfStudy;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String print() {
        return "Student ID: " + studentId + "\n"
                + "First Name: " + firstName + "\n"
                + "Surname: " + surname + "\n"
                + "Email: " + email + "\n"
                + "Year of Study: " + yearOfStudy;
    }

    public void addModule(int id, String mCode, int mMark) {
        if (mods.size() == 4) {
            mods.remove();
        }

        Module module = new Module();
        mods.add(module);
    }

    //this method returns the module list of this student sorted by marks
    public String getModulesSortedByMarks(int id) {
        Object[] sortedMods;
        sortedMods = mods.toArray();

        Arrays.sort(sortedMods);

        String sortedModulesList = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedMods.length; i++) {
            sortedModulesList = "\n" + ((Module) sortedMods[i]).print();
        }
        return sortedModulesList;

    }
}
```

**Module** class below:

```
package studentrecords;

/**
 *
 * @author azim1
 */
public class Module implements Comparable {

    private String moduleCode;
    private int moduleMark;

    public String getModuleCode() {
        return moduleCode;
    }

    public int getModuleMark() {
        return moduleMark;
    }

    public String print() {
        return "Module Code: " + moduleCode + "\n"
                + "Mark: " + moduleMark;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object aModule) {
        if (this.moduleMark == ((Module) aModule).getModuleMark()) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.moduleMark < ((Module) aModule).getModuleMark()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

**Manager** class below:

```
package studentrecords;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author azim1
 */
public class Manager {

    List<Student> studs = new LinkedList<>();
    Student student;

    public void addStudent(Student aNewStudentObj) {

        studs.add(aNewStudentObj);
    }

    public void displayStudent(int studentId) {

        System.out.println(studs.get(studentId));
    }

    public void displayMarks(int studentId) {

        student.getModulesSortedByMarks(studentId);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(int studentId) {

        studs.remove(studentId);
    }

    public void displayAll() {

        for (Student student : studs) {
            student.print();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is **student** getting initialized ?

Comment: @user85421 I would like to use the student id as index because its a unique key.

Comment: @BHAWANISINGH Not sure what you mean sorry. Student objects are made in the Manager class that calls from the Student class.

Comment: @user85421 Maybe using student id as index isn't so good but how do I have it so that I can display the details of a particular student with the student id entered at the GUI?

Comment: @user85421 so are you saying that I should use map instead of linked list to store my student objects?

Comment: @user85421 I would prefer to loop over the list, but how would I do that? With iterator interface?

Comment: @user85421 I appreciate the help btw. Thanks.

Comment: @user85421 Also, when you say I've tried initialising the student field in StudentRecords but still get a null. I typed: `this.student = student;` in the constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select your students by it's studentId I would use a

```
HashMap<Integer, Student>
```

for maintaining your student repository. A Queue is meant for FIFO rsp. LIFO operations.

Comment: I was just told that I could loop over the list instead but would I have to use Iterator interface for that?

Comment: I appreciate the help btw. Cheers.

Comment: Of course you can iterate on a collection and do what you want with each item. But: you could also implement your own assembler code doing the same. But I recommend you to use the provided java classes in the sense for which they are foreseen.

Comment: Awesome, one more question, I've tried to initialise the `Student` field in `StudentRecords` by placing: `this.student = student` in the constructor but I am still getting a null for some reason?